# Cannot filter array into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have categories array which contains object array of specializations. When I am trying to filter it by specializations, something goes wrong(The category list which must not change and hold all data, it changes too. And when I delete letters from search list of data doesn`t come back) . I have tried lots of methods and at the end code become like this(I know that it is not good code, but I have tried lots of things and just tired typing it);

This is my filter method:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const { categories } = prevState;

  let filtered = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    let newCategory = categories[i];
    const { specializations } = categories[i];
    let newSpecs = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < specializations.length; j++) {
      const { specName } = specializations[j];
      if (specName.indexOf(search) !== -1) {
        newSpecs.push(specializations[j]);
      }
    };
    newCategory.specializations = newSpecs;
    if (newSpecs.length>0) {
      filtered.push(newCategory);
    }
  }

  return {resultCategories:filtered}
});
```

This is how I render:

```
category.specializations.map(
    (spec, index) =>
      (index < 5 || collapsed[cat_index]) && (
        <Text
          onPress={() =>
            this.props.navigation.navigate("CreateOrderSecond", {
              spec: spec.id
            })
          }
          style={styles.specs}
          key={index}
        >
          {spec.specName}
        </Text>
      )
  );
```

How looks like categories:

```
Category{
 avatar Image{...}
 categoryName   string
 created    string($date-time)
 id integer($int64)
 lastUpdated    string($date-time)
 specializations    [Specialization{
                       avatar   Image{...}
                       created  string($date-time)
                       id   integer($int64)
                       lastUpdated  string($date-time)
                       masterName   string
                       specName string
                     }]
 }
```

Comment: Please include that what your actual json looks like and what's your desired json?

Comment: I included the Swagger Model of Category. There are array of specializations in categories and I just need filter the list of specializations by search string

Comment: you want the specializations against each category?

Comment: Yes, specializations must stay in categories

Comment: Looks like something is passed by reference and not value, so your original object is being modified, when you merely want to use the value without modifying the original object. You have to pass/copy the object and not just assign it, which happens to be by reference. (I didn't get into the details here, but that is what I think is most likely going on)

Comment: Yes It is. But I cant find where I did it wrong.  I have 2 state values. resultCategories and categories. I assign new const by categories then filter it. I think problem is here  const { categories } = prevState;

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```js
category = {
  specializations : [
    {
      created : 2312121,
      id   : 1,
      lastUpdated  : "24-01-2020",
      masterName   : "ProductOne",
      specName :  "Food"
    },
    {
      created : 2312121,
      id   : 1,
      lastUpdated  : "24-01-2020",
      masterName   : "ProductTwo",
      specName :  "Sopping"
    },
    {
      created : 2312121,
      id   : 1,
      lastUpdated  : "24-01-2020",
      masterName   : "ProductThree",
      specName :  "Food"
    }
  ]
}
searchValue = "Food"
let results = category.specializations.filter(specialization => specialization.specName === searchValue)


console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you, but maybe utilize your `.filter` and `.map` Array methods to slim down the code:

```js
const search = 'Your Search String';

const possible_slight_improvement = prevState => {
  const { categories } = prevState; // Pull categories out of prevState

  const resultCategories = categories
    .map(({ specializations = [] }) => specializations.filter(({ specName }) => specName === search))
    .filter(specializations => specializations.length > 0);

  // resultCategories will be an array of arrays that have specializations in them
  // categories will be unchanged
  return { resultCategories };
};

this.setState(possible_slight_improvement);
```

Comment: I tried this. But error is showing up. I think structure little bit changed. I am trying to refactor your code